# Need Suggestion | Unit test | Flexible data prepartion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, design-patterns

we are writing lot of unit test cases for our our requirement and i see below pattern while preparing the data

we are sending one entity which has around 20 attributes and out of them 12-15 are common and rest of the values needs to be changed as per the requirement

I see repeatitive code in my team as they used to create a instance and create all properties and send this object.

Have refactored this create a class which derives from original class  and set the common properties in constructor in this class. so this way i will get the common values by the time i create object and for other i used to set in scenarios

but some how i fell this is not much a good pattern and was looking for some better pattern here which is more flexible and maintainable

Can we have a Helper class which will XML entries as that of class and will have extra attribute for scenario and get the data according to scenario but still this seems to be not maintainable

Can some provide some design suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement some static method that creates a default object instance. This method can be a part of the object itself, an extension method or a private method of your unit test class - whatever you prefer.

Like this:

```
public class Person
{
    // Properties...

    public static Person GetDefaultInstance()
    {
        return new Person()
        {
            // Set default properties here...
        };
    }
}
```

Then, you can add some fluent API methods and use them to overwrite default properties:

```
public Person LivesAt(string address)
{
    Address = address;
    return this;
}
```

That way, you can initialize your object under test like this:

```
var person = Person.GetDefaultInstance()
                   .LivesAt("5th Avenue")
                   .WorksAt("Google");
```

So it becomes clear which properties of the default instance you are changing for that particular unit test.